# How to load a captcha image in image view? (Hotlinking the Captcha)

Tags: java, android, imageview, captcha

I'm trying to create a login form which loads the captcha from a specific url "http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmsip/" into image view. But I'm unable to do so... What would be the best way to achieve this?

This is the code of the Java Class File below:

```java
Document document = null;
try {
    document = Jsoup.connect("http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmsip/").ignoreContentType(true).get();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Element captchaElement = document.select("#divmain img").first();
String captchaImgSrc = captchaElement.attr("src");
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = new URL("http://evarsity.srmuniv.ac.in/srmsip/" + captchaImgSrc).openStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap captcha = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
ImageView captchaImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
captchaImage.setImageBitmap(captcha);
```

The image view either crashes showing nullPointer or with white colour background and in the last second line of the code the (ImageView) shows Casting is redundant.